Scifi Movie or TV Series that I watched somewhere within 1990-2005
I remember little about the movie, but the plot was: in modern world wizards or mages or sorcerers exist and there are magic items.
I also remember a boy or guy riding near some rocks on the river where there were powerline powers and powerlines and he was transported to an other world where flying ships existed.
One very powerful item was a Belt, which most of the soldiers had. Moving your hands in a spinning motion generated a orb that could be thrown at your enemy.
I'm sorry this is all I can remember as I was very young at the time, but I would love to find this movie or TV series.

My first thought after reading your question was Spellbinder.
Some citations from Wikipedia:

While at the camp, Paul Reynolds accidentally goes into a parallel universe. This other world is inhabited by a more hierarchic and technologically different society, ruled by a group of people known as Spellbinders. Paul meets a girl there named Riana, and they become friends. The Spellbinders have discovered the power to create and manipulate static electricity. They fly in gigantic copper-coloured machines that utilize large rotating orange crystals, presumably creating some form of magnetic levitation.
The power suit is the central piece of Spellbinder technology. It is powered by a set of power stones, which can be recharged in the castle complex. By rubbing the cuffs of the suit together, a Spellbinder can generate and discharge a power bolt.


Sounds like Spellbinder. It was on the Disney Channel along with Ocean Girl in the 90's, both syndicated from Australia. I watched both :-)
